# Can prime number solutions $a$,$b$,$c$ exist for $a^2+b^3=c^4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I stumbled upon this question while browsing number theory problems online. Clearly, cases when only one of a or b are either odd or even, and then c is odd only hold. This problem was solved on a website. This is quoted from the solution of that website:
[part of a math solution for a number theory problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwylU.png)

The problem is how did he conclude that $(c^2-a)$ is a prime? A case that would contradict such conclusion is: $11^2-2=17*7$ if a is even, and $11^2-5=29*2^2$ if b is even.

Comment: Aren't they assuming that $a,b,c$ are all prime numbers? In which case, $c^2-a$ is prime, because $b=c^2-a$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the logic here. If $x$ is prime and $x^2=y*z$ for some $y<z$, does that mean $y$ is prime?

Answer (score 2):

If yes, then $$b^3 = (c^2-a)(c^2+a)\implies$$ $$c^2+a = b^2 \;\;\wedge\;\; c^2-a=b$$ or $$c^2+a = b^3 \;\;\wedge\;\; c^2-a=1$$

In 1. case you get $2a = b(b-1)$ so if $b>3$ then $a$ is composite so $b=3$ (clearly $b\ne 2$) and $a=3$, so $c^2 =6$, impossibile.

In 2. case we have $2a= (b-1)(b^2+b+1)$ so if $b>2$ then $a$ is composite...